VSCodeでC/C++のビルドを言語別に切り替えたい
概要
VSCodeでC/C++を書いています。一つのプロジェクトにC,C++が混在しており、両方に対してtasks.jsonが定義されています。
ここで、"コマンドパレット" -> "Tasks: Run task" から定義された任意のタスクを呼び出すことができますが、 F5 から直接呼び出すこともできると思います。
しかし、 F5 で呼ぶとCプログラムに対してC++用のタスクを呼び出したり、C++プログラムに対してC用のタスクを呼び出されたりするわけです。そういうわけで、言語別にビルドタスクを切り替えたいのです。
環境

Windows 11
Ubuntu 24.04 on WSL2
GCC 4:13.2.0-7ubuntu1

設定
tasks.json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C++ BUILD AND RUN ACTIVE FILE",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-I",
                "~/ac-library-master",
                "-W",
                "-Wall",
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "label": "CLANG BUILD AND RUN ACTIVE FILE",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "detail": "Task for building and running C program"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc アクティブなファイルのビルド",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "デバッガーによって生成されたタスク。"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**", "~/ac-library-master"],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c23",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++23",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

補足
coderunnerも考えましたが、できればデフォルトの機能で済ませたいです。
ドキュメントも斜め読みしたんですが、浅学も相まってよくわかりませんでした。

古いですがこの記事とか参考になるのでは？ Visual Studio Codeで言語ごとに別のキーバインドを割り当てる のkeybindings.json を使った設定の方法 そしてドキュメントはこちらでしょう。Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code
